# disabling swiping on uipageviewcontroller for certain area of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a uipageviewcontroller and the pages have an area on the screen where there is a uitableview. I want the user to only be able to swipe through pages outside of that uitableview.

I can't seem to find where these gesture recognizers are hiding. I am setting them up as delegates like this:

```
self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController?.gestureRecognizers
for gesture in self.view.gestureRecognizers!{
            // get the good one, i discover there are 2
            if(gesture is UIPanGestureRecognizer)
            {
                println("ispan")
                // replace delegate by yours (Do not forget to implement the gesture protocol)
                (gesture as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).delegate = self
            }
        }
```

I am seeing ispan in the logs so it seems to find some uipangesturerecognizer but when I override the function like this:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    println("gesture should begin")
    var point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    return true
}
```

it doesn't print out "gesture should begin" at all... I have the class set as a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` what am I doing wrong? I'm guessing I have the wrong gesture recognizers set as delegates how can I set the correct ones as delegates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could something like this work?

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    if(touch.view == <your tableView>){
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
```

You might need to also test which gestureRecognizer it is (the one from the pageView or the one from the tableView).

Comment: this would definitely work I think. The issue is I can't get any of the delegate methods to be called.